# Certbot https not working for example.com, only for www.example.com

Tags: ssl, https, httpd, cpanel, certbot

[UPDATE] - I have posted it into the wrong site, so I will copy-paste this topic into the Unix/Linux community. So please delete this topic!

I have installed SSL certificate on my webserver and enabled redirection of all http requests to https. So far this works when I try to open www.example.com but not with example.com. Just for the record I have changed my domain.com with example.com. I have checked my `access_log` and `error.log` and all of them doesn't show any new entries when I try to open example.com in a browser.

```
curl https://example.com

curl: (60) Issuer certificate is invalid.
More details here: http://curl.haxx.se/docs/sslcerts.html

curl performs SSL certificate verification by default, using a "bundle"
 of Certificate Authority (CA) public keys (CA certs). If the default
 bundle file isn't adequate, you can specify an alternate file
 using the --cacert option.
If this HTTPS server uses a certificate signed by a CA represented in
 the bundle, the certificate verification probably failed due to a
 problem with the certificate (it might be expired, or the name might
 not match the domain name in the URL).
If you'd like to turn off curl's verification of the certificate, use
 the -k (or --insecure) option.
```

When I execute the same curl command with www.example.com I got to my website. I am using

```
-bash-4.2$ hostname
example
-bash-4.2$ hostname -f
example.com
```

My hostname in `/etc/sysconfig/network` is example. I am also using vhost file:

```
cat /etc/httpd/sites-available/example.conf
<VirtualHost *:80>

    ServerName www.example.com
    ServerAlias example.com
    DocumentRoot /var/www/html
    ErrorLog /var/www/html/error.log
    CustomLog /var/www/html/requests.log combined
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{SERVER_NAME} =www.example.com [OR]
RewriteCond %{SERVER_NAME} =example.com
RewriteRule ^ https://%{SERVER_NAME}%{REQUEST_URI} [END,QSA,R=permanent]
</VirtualHost>
```

and in the httpd.conf I have set to load configuration files from `/etc/httpd/sites-available/*.conf`

The other problem is that when I try to install Cpanel it gives me the following error:

```
2017-03-15 14:10:39  501 ( INFO): Validating that the system hostname ('example') is a FQDN...
2017-03-15 14:10:39  507 (ERROR):
2017-03-15 14:10:39  508 (ERROR): ********************* ERROR *********************
2017-03-15 14:10:39  509 (ERROR):
2017-03-15 14:10:39  510 (ERROR): Your hostname (example) is invalid, and must be
2017-03-15 14:10:39  511 (ERROR): set to a fully qualified domain name before installing cPanel.
2017-03-15 14:10:39  512 (ERROR):
2017-03-15 14:10:39  513 (ERROR): A fully qualified domain name must contain two dots, and consists of two parts: the hostname and the domain name.
2017-03-15 14:10:39  514 (ERROR): You can update your hostname by running `hostname your-hostname.example.com`, then re-running the installer.
2017-03-15 14:10:39  516 (ERROR): ********************* ERROR *********************
2017-03-15 14:10:39  517 (FATAL): Exiting...
Removing /root/installer.lock.
```

And this is my SSL VHOST file which was automatically generated by let's encrypt:

```
    <IfModule mod_ssl.c>
<VirtualHost *:443>

    ServerName www.example.com
    ServerAlias example.com
    DocumentRoot /var/www/html
    ErrorLog /var/www/html/error.log
    CustomLog /var/www/html/requests.log combined
RewriteEngine on
SSLCertificateFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/example.com/cert.pem
SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/example.com/privkey.pem
Include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-apache.conf
SSLCertificateChainFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/example.com/chain.pem
</VirtualHost>
</IfModule>
```

A bit more debugging information:

```
curl -l example.com
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//IETF//DTD HTML 2.0//EN">
<html><head>
<title>301 Moved Permanently</title>
</head><body>
<h1>Moved Permanently</h1>
<p>The document has moved <a href="https://example.com/">here</a>.</p>
</body></html>

curl https://example.com
curl: (60) Issuer certificate is invalid.
More details here: http://curl.haxx.se/docs/sslcerts.html

curl performs SSL certificate verification by default, using a "bundle"
 of Certificate Authority (CA) public keys (CA certs). If the default
 bundle file isn't adequate, you can specify an alternate file
 using the --cacert option.
If this HTTPS server uses a certificate signed by a CA represented in
 the bundle, the certificate verification probably failed due to a
 problem with the certificate (it might be expired, or the name might
 not match the domain name in the URL).
If you'd like to turn off curl's verification of the certificate, use
 the -k (or --insecure) option.

curl -l www.example.com
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//IETF//DTD HTML 2.0//EN">
<html><head>
<title>301 Moved Permanently</title>
</head><body>
<h1>Moved Permanently</h1>
<p>The document has moved <a href="https://www.example.com/">here</a>.</p>
</body></html>
```

And when I run `curl -l https://www.example.com` my website is loading, which means that it is passing the SSL certificate check and the problem is only with the example.com certificate. So I guess my VHOST files are completely messed up. I tried to reinstall them but I think it didn't work.

Comment: Can you please post the virtualhost with the certificate?

Comment: @orphans I think I have posted the virtualhost, what do you mean with the certificate?

Comment: You only posted the VirtualHost for the HTTP site and not the HTTPS.

Comment: @Orphans I have added my HTTPS VHOST file in the original thread on the bottom.

Comment: what is your response when you run curl -I http://example.com ? and curl -I http://www.example.com

Comment: @Orphans I added the information in the original thread.

Comment: According to you, you run "curl -I wwww.example.com" which look strange

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/55468/discussion-between-georg-stoyanov-and-orphans).

Answer (score 1):

After deep investigation it appeared that the problem was that the requests to example.com was using the default ssl certificate which was defined in the `/etc/httpd/conf.d/ssl.conf`, so I have commented the three lines containing the key, certificate itself and the chain file and added the path to the let's encrypt certificates

```
SSLCertificateFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/example.com/cert.pem
SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/example.com/privkey.pem
SSLCertificateChainFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/example.com/chain.pem
```

Then I have reloaded the httpd service and checked the status using:

https://www.ssllabs.com/ssltest/analyze.html?d=example.com
https://www.ssllabs.com/ssltest/analyze.html?d=www.example.com

you can check your SSL certificates also using:

```
openssl rsa -in privateKey.key -check
openssl x509 -in certificate.crt -text -noout
```

And you can check your SSL certificates using:

```
openssl s_client -connect www.example.com:443
openssl s_client -connect example.com:443
```

So when I have compared both certificates I saw that the example.com is using the localhost.crt certificate and then I issued a find command to find where this certificate was configured and found out that it was in the ssl.conf file only configured, so this is how I fixed the problem.